# How to change "arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0" to "localhost" in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need Help with npm start.

four months ago I have a react app that worked fine and the local server was "localhost". I don’t know what happened with my app `localhost` became `arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0`, but now when I launch this app I get this:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view kok-app in the browser.

  http://arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify what tool you used to create the app?

The following answer relates just to the change of the port. If it's the entire endpoint, I'm afraid I'll need more information (also, what would be the expected output - Is it `localhost`?).

If you used the toolchain/environment called `create-react-app`, then you can create a file called `.env` in the project root and then put this line in there (amongst possible other env-vars):

```
PORT=4000
```

And change the port to the one you want to use. Then deploy the development server again.

Note, according to the documentation:

> Note: this feature is available with react-scripts@0.5.0 and higher.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Vilches, I update my question. Do you have any idea what to get the localhost instead of darwin?

Comment: @Talm I found this similar issue on Github, and it has a solution, it may help. It also uses the `.env` file and you have to type `HOST=localhost` in it. I haven't tested it, and I'm not sure if there's a better (more natural) way to do this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2954